# How to convert String to JsonPatch?

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-patch

Java String which I retrieved from the database:

```
[
  { "op": "replace", "path": "/baz", "value": "boo" },
  { "op": "add", "path": "/hello", "value": ["world"] },
  { "op": "remove", "path": "/foo" }
]
```

How can I convert it to a `JsonPatch` object?

I am using `com.github.fge.jsonpatch` library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on JSON Patch documentation, you can build a JsonPatch instance using Jackson deserialization.

```
 String json = "...";

 final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 final InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes());
 final JsonPatch patch = mapper.readValue(in, JsonPatch.class);
```

Comment: Works like magic! I had error when just using "objectMapper.convertValue(inputJsonString, JsonNode.class)", the escaped double quotes would stay and it would be invalid json...